# Magento - automatically export all products at 00:01 at first day of the month

Tags: magento-1.8, product, cron, export, importexport

i would like to automatically export all products of my webshop at the first day of the month right after 00:00.

I do know how to export them manually with the export functionality and know how to set a cron for this.

But is there to export all products with the attributes? 
And preferably only all products with qty 1 or more ...

I have Magento 1.8.1 CE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

By using this code. Naming this: `export_mail.php`

```
<?php

/***********************
 * Import/Export Script to run Import/Export profile
 * from command line or cron. Cleans entries from dataflow_batch_(import|export) table
 ***********************/

$mageconf = './app/etc/local.xml';  // Mage local.xml config
$mageapp  = './app/Mage.php';       // Mage app location
$logfile  = 'export_data.log';      // Import/Export log file

/* uncomment following block when moved to server - to ensure this page is
 * not accessed from anywhere else
 */

if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== 'server ip') {
 die("You are not a cron job!");
}


/* System -> Import/Export -> Profiles get profile ID from
 * Magento Import/Export Profiles
 */

$profileId = 2;

/* Post run housekeeping table bloat removal
 * imports use "dataflow_batch_import" table
 * exports use "dataflow_batch_export" table
 */

$table = 'dataflow_batch_export';

/* Scan Magento local.xml file for connection information */

if (file_exists($mageconf)) {

$xml = simplexml_load_file($mageconf, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$db['host'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
$db['name'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
$db['user'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
$db['pass'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
$db['pref'] = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;

}

else {
    Mage::log('Export script failed to open Mage local.xml', null, $logfile);
    exit('Failed to open Mage local.xml');
}


/* Initialize profile to be run as Magento Admin and log start of export */

require_once $mageapp;
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
$profile->load($profileId);
if (!$profile->getId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('ERROR: Incorrect profile id');
}

Mage::log('Export ' . $profileId . ' Started.', null, $logfile);

Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$recordCount = 0;
$batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');

Mage::log('Export '.$profileId.' Complete. BatchID: '.$batchModel->getId(), null, $logfile);

echo "Export Complete. BatchID: " . $batchModel->getId() . "\n";
/* sent file */
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask( 0 );
Mage :: app( "default" );
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
$mail->setBodyHtml($html_body);
$mail->setFrom('admin@mywebsite.com', 'Admin');
$mail->addTo('info@mywebsite.com', 'Info');
$mail->setSubject('export_product_stocks');
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir();
$path = $dir.DS.'var'.DS.'export'.DS.'export_product_stocks.csv';
$file = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($path));
$file ->type        = 'text/csv';
$file ->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
$file ->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$file ->filename    = 'export_product_stocks.csv';
$mail->send();
echo "E-mail sent";


/* Connect to Magento database */

sleep(30);

mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db['name']) or die(mysql_error());

/* Truncate dataflow_batch_(import|export) table for housecleaning */

$querystring = "TRUNCATE ".$db['pref'].$table;

mysql_query($querystring) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Which is being run with a cronjob by: `wget http://mywebsite.com/export_mail.php`